# WMS Meteorological Data sources?

Tags: wms, natural-disaster

I was looking in Google Earth and saw lots of feeds/KMZ for historical and current Hurricanes.

I am after some Meteorological WMS feeds into data that is related to past and present hurricanes and topical storms [like [Irene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Irene_%282011%29) (2011)] so that I can create a mashup, most likely in one of the ESRI APIs.

Meteorological data in particular, but anything else you think would be relevant.

Comment: If you could rephrase this as a request for data sources concerning hurricanes *in general,* it would be appropriate for our site.  Because it is so localized in time and space, despite its obvious interest, it simply does not fit our scope.  Sorry.

Comment: A good idea would be to leave a note in the chat room and see if you can get recommendations there... unfortunately, it hardly gets enough traffic to be a reliable source. This is one of the times I feel GIS.SE can fall a bit short in fulfilling its mission.

Comment: re-opend and made the question more generic for GISse guidelines.

Comment: Understood and good move

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the WMS links here:

[NOAA National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov/gis/otherpage.htm)

[NOAA Ocean Service's nowCOAST's Map Services](http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/help/mapservices.shtml?name=mapservices)

Answer (score 5):

**NASA - LANCE - Rapid Response Web Mapping Service:**

(Land Atmosphere Near real-time Capability for EOS)

http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/wms/?zoom=6&lat=22.48608&lon=-72.55444&layers=000B0FTFFFFT&datum1=08%2F24%2F2011

[image]

**WMS Sources** are listed in the code - most are going through [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/)
but some are direct WMS calls that can be use (get permission) to render in other web mapping applications (such as ArcGIS API's)

```
        var Terra250 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Terra250m_MODIS-bands1,4,3", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Terra250]=DATA+terr_250m"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Terra250",map: 'rrglobal_terra_250m.map'});

    var Terra250_367 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Terra250m_MODIS-bands3,6,7", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Terra250_367]=DATA+terr_367"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Terra250_367",format: "image/jpeg;mode=24bit",map: 'rrglobal_terra250_367.map'});

    var Terra250_721 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Terra250m_MODIS-bands7,2,1", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Terra250_721]=DATA+terr_721"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Terra250_721",format: "image/jpeg;mode=24bit",map: 'rrglobal_terra250_721.map'});

    var Aqua250 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Aqua250m_MODIS-bands1,4,3", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Aqua250]=DATA+aqua_250m"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Aqua250",format: "image/jpeg;mode=24bit",map: 'rrglobal_aqua_250m.map'}, {singleTile:false});

    var Aqua250_721 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Aqua250m_MODIS-bands7,2,1", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Aqua250_721]=DATA+aqua_721"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Aqua250_721",format: "image/jpeg;mode=24bit",map: 'rrglobal_aqua250_721.map'});


    map.addLayers([Terra250, Terra250_367, Terra250_721, Aqua250, Aqua250_721]);

    var Terra250 = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Terra250m_MODIS-bands1,4,3", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[Terra250]=DATA+terr_250m"+ dateValue + ".vrt",
            {layers:"Terra250",map: 'rrglobal_terra_250m.map'}, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true});

    var firmfires24hr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Fires Last 24 Hours", 
        "http://firefly.geog.umd.edu/wms/wms?", 
        {layers:"fires24",srs: 'EPSG:4326', transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true});

    var firmfires48hr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Fires Last 48 Hours", 
        "http://firefly.geog.umd.edu/wms/wms?", 
        {layers:"fires48",srs: 'EPSG:4326', transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true});

    gpwv3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "SEDAC gpw-v3 Population Density", 
        "http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms?", 
        {layers:"gpw-v3:gpw-v3-population-density-future-estimates_2010", STYLES: 'grump-v1-population-density_2000:100-plus-persons-per-sq-km', transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true, opacity:0.9});

    var grumpv1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "SEDAC grump-v1 Population Density", 
        "http://beta.sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu:8080/geoserver/wms?", 
        {layers:"grump-v1:grump-v1-population-density_2000", transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true, opacity:0.9});

    var AMSR_E_RainRate_D = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "AMSR_E_RainRate_D", 
        "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[rain_D]=DATA+AMSR_E_L2_Rain_R11_"+ amsreDate + "_D_RR_geo.png"+"&map_imagetype=AGG", 
        {layers:"rain_D",map: 'AMSR_E_rain_rate_D.map',srs: 'EPSG:4326', format: 'image/png', transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true});

    var AMSR_E_RainRate_A = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "AMSR_E_RainRate_A", 
        "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?map_layer[rain_A]=DATA+AMSR_E_L2_Rain_R11_"+ amsreDate + "_A_RR_geo.png"+"&map_imagetype=AGG", 
        {layers:"rain_A",map: 'AMSR_E_rain_rate_A.map',srs: 'EPSG:4326', format: 'image/png', transparent:true }, {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:false, alpha:true});

    var country_bound = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "Countries", 
            "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?&map_imagetype=AGG", 
            {layers:"countries",map: 'global_WMS_test.map', transparent:true},  {isBaseLayer:false, visibility:true});

    map.addLayers([ AMSR_E_RainRate_D, AMSR_E_RainRate_A, gpwv3, Terra250, firmfires24hr, firmfires48hr, country_bound]);
//    map.addLayers([AMSR_E_RainRate, country_bound]);

var ov = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "OpenLayers WMS", "/cgi-bin/mapserv.cgi?", {layers:"countries",map: 'global_WMS_test.map' } );
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a WMS source, but ESRI has a mashup relating to it:

http://tmapps.esri.com/hurricane/index.html?locate=Locate&baseMap=lyrTopo&visLyrs=HC|PC|WW|SG|YT|TW|FL|&ytkw=tropical%20storm&twkw=%23irene&flkw=hurricane&xmin=-12302981.112856865&ymin=1404619.7568966309&xmax=-5689037.929398893&ymax=5235032.118322365

And the GIS sources: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/